# Как вынести объект за пределы блока Main?

Tags: c#, классы, объекты

```
namespace learning
{
    public class LibraryOfPrice
    {
        public string NameWork;
        public string Unit;
        public int Price;
        public LibraryOfPrice(string nameWork, string unit, int price)
        {
            NameWork = nameWork;
            Unit = unit;
            Price = price;
        }
    }

    internal class Program
    {
        LibraryOfPrice newObject = new LibraryOfPrice("форма гранит", "шт", 30000);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write(newObject.NameWork);
        }
    }
}
```

Подскажите, что не так со строкой, где создается объект "newObject"(строка прям над блоком Main). Мне в блоке Main нужно вывести одно из полей данного объекта, но ссылка на объект не работает. Мне нужно что-бы все экземпляры были за пределами блока мейн, или же в коллекциях, но ссылаться в коллекциях не получается.

Comment: `newObject` - нигде не используется, следовательно нет смысла его куда-то выносить, с другой стороны в это случае можно просто скопировать эту строку вне main. Пока этот объект нигде не используется - нет никакой разницы. Отредактируй вопрос так, чтобы стало видно что именно ты хочешь сделать и какую ошибку при этом получаешь. Отредактировать вопрос можно с помощью кнопки [edit] под вопросом

Comment: Пожалуйста, создайте [mcve]. Очень много кода, который не относится к проблеме.

Answer (score 2):

Так как использование подразумевается в статическом методе - поле тоже нужно сделать статическим:

```
static LibraryOfPrice newObject = new LibraryOfPrice("форма гранит", "шт", 30000);
```